# cannot run sudo

Tags: macos, sudo

I have a corporate account `work` on my macbook that has administrator privileges and created a non-administrative account `local`.

Logged in as `local`, when I tried a command with sudo, I got the familiar `is not in the sudoers file`.

The file `/etc/sudoers` is owned by the usual `root/wheel`. I tried to modify the file inside a `su work` shell but it was readonly for that user. Then I tried `su root` but that didn't work either. Then I found out that I need to [enable to the root user](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528).

I enabled the root user, but still cannot `su root`, still get the same terse `su: Sorry`. I seem to have enabled the root user correctly, since the process to enable it now gives the option to disable it or change password.

How can I get `su` to work for user `local`? Is there a another way to allow the user `local` to use `sudo`?

Comment: You do not need to enable root - the normal way is from the admin account `sudo visudo` which opens vi on the sudoers file

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that is exactly what I ended up doing. I think I first tried `sudo visudo` inside a `su - <admin-account>` but it failed and later the samething from a `ssh <admin-account>@localhost` did, I could be wrong but now my non-privileged account is in `sudoers` and I am happy camper.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the I was able to modify `/etc/sudoers` when I logged in as `work` using `ssh`. Not sure if I had made some mistake with my previous attempt with `su - work`.

The following steps worked:

- Logged in as `local`, start with `ssh work@localhost`
- `sudo visudo`
- Add entry `local   ALL=(ALL) ALL`
- Save and exist vi
- Exist ssh session
- Try `sudo ls /`

Comment: The issue is you need to be an admin user to edit sudoers and so you have to be logged in as work.